# the underlying connection was closed the connection was closed unexpectedly on WSDL service

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I am using a WSDL service and I am connected properly. The problem come after many calls to a method of the API inside a foreach.

```
foreach (var tyre in tyresResponse)
{
    getDetails getDetails = new getDetails();
    getDetailsRequest getDetailsRequest = new getDetailsRequest();
    getDetails.token = authResponse.token;
    getDetails.itemId = tyre.itemId.ToString();
    getDetailsRequest.getDetails = getDetails;
    var detailsResponse = webService.getDetails(getDetails); //<- here the error
}
```

After +/- 150 calls it gives the following error:

```
[WebException: The underlying connection was closed the connection was closed unexpectedly..]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1694
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +86
```

What could it be? I added in my web.config this in the binding attribute:

```
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" openTimeout="01:10:00" closeTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00"
```

Comment: `The underlying connection was closed` usually occurs if service being called stops to work (for some reason like out of memory, stack overflow, db query error). You may check a service log (debug output) to get some additional information.

Comment: it isn't my service though, how can I debug it?

Comment: You may ask service author is there service log available. You may decompile the service with tool like ILSpy if it was created with .Net Framework (Core) and you have access to service binaries. You may turn [wcf tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) and [message logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging) if can access service configuration file (it requires service to be restarted)